# How to make Android GMail app to show my picture next to my email messages?

Tags: gmail, profiles

I have a user profile picture selected for my own Google profile. This picture is visible in my GMail settings and works fine with web versions of GMail:

- This profile picture shows successfully next to all my email messages on GMail web site, i.e. when I open my GMail account through desktop web browser (Chrome).
- This profile picture also shows successfully when I open mobile version of GMail web site using mobile Chrome on my Nexus 5.

However, when I use the stock Android GMail app to read my emails on Nexus 5, my profile picture refuses to show. Profile pictures of other people show successfully next to their message titles, but my messages are displayed with the "default" profile icon - a large "A" in a square. Meanwhile, GMail app correctly recognizes these messages as posted by me: it explicitly says "me" in place of sender's name.

So, is there some sort of trick to make GMail app behave consistently with GMail web site in that regard, i.e. make it display my profile picture next to me messages in GMail?

Comment: I totally agree with you and this is really an annoying bug. One question thou, do you use Chrome and does it show image for that profile, at my PC Chrome is also not showing correct image.